# Soap call in Python

Tags: python, soap, soappy

I tried to call a soap service. My call is success but its returns empty value.Below i attached my soap request and response schema. Its takes 1d array as input and return that array.

> Request Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CalculateWeb1D xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <HCID>string</HCID>
      <jaggedobjDataMICRO>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </jaggedobjDataMICRO>
      <numeratorID>int</numeratorID>
    </CalculateWeb1D>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

> Response Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CalculateWeb1DResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CalculateWeb1DResult>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </CalculateWeb1DResult>
    </CalculateWeb1DResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

> My code to call soap service

```
from SOAPpy import WSDL

import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore',DeprecationWarning)
import SOAPpy

wsdlFile = 'http://204.9.76.243/nuCast.DataFeedService/Service1.asmx?WSDL'
server = WSDL.Proxy(wsdlFile)
server.soapproxy.config.dumpSOAPOut = 1
server.soapproxy.config.dumpSOAPIn = 1
print server.CalculateWeb1D(str(1073757),[1,2],99)
```

> and my output

```
*** Outgoing SOAP ******************************************************
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<CalculateWeb1D SOAP-ENC:root="1">
<v1 xsi:type="xsd:string">1073757</v1>
<v2 SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:int[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<item>1</item>
<item>2</item>
</v2>
<v3 xsi:type="xsd:int">99</v3>
</CalculateWeb1D>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
************************************************************************
*** Incoming SOAP ******************************************************
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><CalculateWeb1DResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
************************************************************************
<SOAPpy.Types.structType CalculateWeb1DResponse at 171814380>: {}
```

Plz help me to find a solution ....

Comment: The solution to what? What is the *particular* question?

Comment: Sorry.In my code return an empty set. Actually web service return the input array . I dont know why its return an empty set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a working version that uses [`suds` client](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import, ImportDoctor
from suds.client import Client

# enable logging to see transmitted XML
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# fix broken wsdl
# add <s:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/> to the wsdl
imp = Import('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
             location='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd')
imp.filter.add('http://tempuri.org/')
wsdl_url = 'http://204.9.76.243/nuCast.DataFeedService/Service1.asmx?WSDL'
client = Client(wsdl_url, doctor=ImportDoctor(imp))

# make request
arrayofstring = client.factory.create('ArrayOfString')
arrayofstring.string = [1,2]
print client.service.CalculateWeb1D(1073757, arrayofstring, 99).string
```

#### Request

```
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (
   http://204.9.76.243/nuCast.DataFeedService/Service1.asmx)
message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/"
   xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:CalculateWeb1D>
         <ns0:HCID>1073757</ns0:HCID>
         <ns0:jaggedobjDataMICRO>
            <ns0:string>1</ns0:string>
            <ns0:string>2</ns0:string>
         </ns0:jaggedobjDataMICRO>
         <ns0:numeratorID>99</ns0:numeratorID>
      </ns0:CalculateWeb1D>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {
  'SOAPAction': u'"http://tempuri.org/CalculateWeb1D"',
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
```

#### Response

```
DEBUG:suds.client:http succeeded:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <CalculateWeb1DResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CalculateWeb1DResult>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>2</string>
      </CalculateWeb1DResult>
    </CalculateWeb1DResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, digging around from a while to find a working SOAP client !