# Soap Client using Suds

Tags: python, soap, suds

> [Soap call in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752923/soap-call-in-python/5760667)

Hi above is  my previous question regarding soap. In there i am passing a 1D array. Now my problem is i need to pass the 2D array to the following Soap schema.

> Request Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CalculateWeb2DObjectArray xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <HCID>string</HCID>
      <jaggedobjDataMICRO>
        <ArrayOfAnyType>
          <anyType />
          <anyType />
        </ArrayOfAnyType>
        <ArrayOfAnyType>
          <anyType />
          <anyType />
        </ArrayOfAnyType>
      </jaggedobjDataMICRO>
      <numeratorID>int</numeratorID>
    </CalculateWeb2DObjectArray>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

> Response Schema

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <CalculateWeb2DObjectArrayResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <CalculateWeb2DObjectArrayResult>
            <ArrayOfAnyType>
              <anyType />
              <anyType />
            </ArrayOfAnyType>
            <ArrayOfAnyType>
              <anyType />
              <anyType />
            </ArrayOfAnyType>
          </CalculateWeb2DObjectArrayResult>
        </CalculateWeb2DObjectArrayResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

> My Code

```
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import, ImportDoctor
from suds.client import Client

# enable logging to see transmitted XML
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# fix broken wsdl
# add <s:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/> to the wsdl
imp = Import('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
             location='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd')
imp.filter.add('http://tempuri.org/')
wsdl_url = 'http://204.9.76.243/nuCast.DataFeedService/Service1.asmx?WSDL'
client = Client(wsdl_url, doctor=ImportDoctor(imp))

# make request
arrayofstring1 = client.factory.create('ArrayOfString')
arrayofstring1.string = [1,2]
arrayofstring2 = client.factory.create('ArrayOfString')
arrayofstring2.string = [5,6]
arrayofstring = client.factory.create('ArrayOfString')
arrayofstring.string = [arrayofstring1,arrayofstring2]


print client.service.CalculateWeb2DObjectArray(1073757, arrayofstring, 99)
```

But i got empty value in output.Plz help to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You pass invalid arguments to `CalculateWeb2DObjectArray()` function.

To find out what type of arguments `CalculateWeb2DObjectArray()` accepts, you could add to your script:

```
print client
```

The output contains:

```
CalculateWeb2DObjectArray(xs:string HCID,
                          ArrayOfArrayOfAnyType jaggedobjDataMICRO,
                          xs:int numeratorID, )
```

So the second argument should be `ArrayOfArrayOfAnyType`, use `client.factory` to create it:

```
aoaoat = client.factory.create('ArrayOfArrayOfAnyType')
```

To find out how to populate `aoaoat`, just print it:

```
print aoaoat
```

The output:

```
(ArrayOfArrayOfAnyType){
  ArrayOfAnyType[] = <empty>
}
```

Repeating the same procedure for `ArrayOfAnyType` you get:

```
(ArrayOfAnyType){
  anyType[] = <empty>
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
aoaoat = client.factory.create('ArrayOfArrayOfAnyType')
lst = aoaoat.ArrayOfAnyType = []
for L in [[1,2], [5,6]]:
    aoat = client.factory.create('ArrayOfAnyType')
    aoat.anyType = L
    lst.append(aoat)
response = client.service.CalculateWeb2DObjectArray(1073757, aoaoat, 99)
print response
```

#### Request

```
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (
  http://204.9.76.243/nuCast.DataFeedService/Service1.asmx)
message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/"
  xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:CalculateWeb2DObjectArray>
         <ns0:HCID>1073757</ns0:HCID>
         <ns0:jaggedobjDataMICRO>
            <ns0:ArrayOfAnyType>
               <ns0:anyType>1</ns0:anyType>
               <ns0:anyType>2</ns0:anyType>
            </ns0:ArrayOfAnyType>
            <ns0:ArrayOfAnyType>
               <ns0:anyType>5</ns0:anyType>
               <ns0:anyType>6</ns0:anyType>
            </ns0:ArrayOfAnyType>
         </ns0:jaggedobjDataMICRO>
         <ns0:numeratorID>99</ns0:numeratorID>
      </ns0:CalculateWeb2DObjectArray>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {
  'SOAPAction': u'"http://tempuri.org/CalculateWeb2DObjectArray"',
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
```

#### Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <CalculateWeb2DObjectArrayResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CalculateWeb2DObjectArrayResult>
        <ArrayOfAnyType>
          <anyType>1</anyType>
          <anyType>2</anyType>
        </ArrayOfAnyType>
        <ArrayOfAnyType>
          <anyType>5</anyType>
          <anyType>6</anyType>
        </ArrayOfAnyType>
      </CalculateWeb2DObjectArrayResult>
    </CalculateWeb2DObjectArrayResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

#### Output

```
(ArrayOfArrayOfAnyType){
   ArrayOfAnyType[] = 
      (ArrayOfAnyType){
         anyType[] = 
            "1",
            "2",
      },
      (ArrayOfAnyType){
         anyType[] = 
            "5",
            "6",
      },
 }
```